# Including optimization constraint in objective function

Tags: optimization

Does solving the following optimization problem :
 $
\min_A \text{Tr} [A \sigma] $ 
such that $
\text{Tr} [A^{-1} \rho] \leq 1 $ 
give the same solution as solving
$
\min_A \text{Tr} [A \sigma]\text{Tr} [A^{-1} \rho] $?,
where $\rho, \sigma \geq 0 $ and $\text{Tr } \rho= \text{Tr } \sigma=1  $, as they are density matrices.
Thank you!

Comment: This is generally not how you roll constraints into a modified objective function. For inequality constraints, look into the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions (which are more or less the generalization of Lagrange multipliers).

Comment: Yes, I understand this not how it is usually done, but I would like to know whether these two optimization problems are equivalent.